# Setting equivalent dtypes for two Pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes with exactly the same column names, but one of the columns has a mismatch in the `dtype`. I'm looking for an elegant way to make their types match (in order to concat them).

Following are the two dataframes:

```
print(full_data_test.dtypes.to_dict())  
{'user_id': dtype('O'), 'days_past': dtype('int64'), 'Income_so_far': dtype('float64'), 'Deposits_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'spins_count_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'fb_invite_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'link_invite_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'video_for_coins_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'video_for_spins_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Spins_Sent_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Coins_Sent_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Spins_Collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Coins_Collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'card_collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'label': dtype('O'), 'os': dtype('O'), 'Media_Source_pid': dtype('O'), 'CPE_Ind': dtype('O'), 'Country': dtype('O'), 'day_of_week_Date_Installed': dtype('O')}

print(padded_train_data.dtypes.to_dict())
{'user_id': dtype('O'), 'days_past': dtype('int64'), 'Income_so_far': dtype('float64'), 'Deposits_so_far': dtype('float64'), 'spins_count_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'fb_invite_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'link_invite_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'video_for_coins_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'video_for_spins_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Spins_Sent_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Coins_Sent_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Spins_Collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'Gifts_Coins_Collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'card_collected_so_far': dtype('int64'), 'label': dtype('O'), 'os': dtype('O'), 'Media_Source_pid': dtype('O'), 'CPE_Ind': dtype('O'), 'Country': dtype('O'), 'day_of_week_Date_Installed': dtype('O')}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How general solution is necessary? `full_data_test = full_data_test.astype(padded_train_data.dtypes)` should working with real data only sometimes, can you specify more situtatios if it failed - what data? What kind of convertion is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest solution is use `astype`:

```
full_data_test = full_data_test.astype(padded_train_data.dtypes)
```

But with general data not always possible - e.g. not possible convert floats to ints if missing values.

You can test not matched columns by and then analyze:

```
mask = full_data_test.dtypes != padded_train_data.dtypes

full_data_test1 = full_data_test[mask]
padded_train_data1 = padded_train_data[mask]
```